# Proccessing nested object in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have the below array of object from get request.

""

```
const submitHandler = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const groupForm = {
        leagueID,
        rank: parseInt(rank)
    }
    try {
        console.log(groupForm)
        const group = await axios.get(`/getGroup/${leagueID}/${parseInt(rank)}`)
        console.log(group)
        const group2 = group.data.map((obj,index)=>{
            const {team, ...rest} = obj;
            return({...rest, name: team.name})
        })
        console.log(group2)
        setGroupTable(group2)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

""

Each object has a nested team object, from which I want to take the value of the team.name and add to parent object. Could someone help and advise me on how I can achieve this?

The reason, for doing this, is that I want array of object which will be retrived in a datatable. From my understand, data table accept an array of object for each row. Hence, I want to take the team.name value to the parent object.

++Update current vs desired array of object sample code

""

```
const group = [
  {
    '_id': "61f9b4b59f6601076fff7682",
    'league': "61f1db496de13b0505f08c83",
    'rank': 1,
    'team': {_id: '61f86e813bce5a7bfce4eb6a', name: 'ZizoTeam'},
    'createdAt': "2022-02-01T22:31:17.808Z",
    'updatedAt': "2022-02-01T22:31:17.808Z",
    '__v': 0
  }
]


const group2 = [
  {
    '_id': "61f9b4b59f6601076fff7682",
    'league': "61f1db496de13b0505f08c83",
    'rank': 1,
    "name": 'ZizoTeam',
    'createdAt': "2022-02-01T22:31:17.808Z",
    'updatedAt': "2022-02-01T22:31:17.808Z",
    '__v': 0
  }
]
```

""

Server query

""

```
    const teamsInGroup = await Group.find({league:req.params.leagueID, rank: req.params.rank}).populate('team', 'name')
    console.log(teamsInGroup)
    res.status(200).json(teamsInGroup)
```

""

Comment: can you paste your sample document as text and show us what is your expected result? You can simplify it as much as possible (just leave one team etc)

Comment: Updated the post, please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const group2 = group.map(obj => {
  return {
    ...obj,
    team: obj.team.name,
  };
}
);
console.log(group2);
```

and to align with your output if you don't need team object and instead only want name

```
const group2 = group.map(obj => {
  const { team, ...rest } = obj;
  return { ...rest, name: team.name };
});
console.log(group2);
```

Comment: I had tried this solution, but I get each object nested into another array and the team name come up as undefined.

Comment: Can you paste your sample file or elaborate more or the above? Using second piece of code and your input, I'm able to get your desired output. Also can you show what output you're getting to elaborate further on your comment?

Comment: edited my code in the post, please let me know if you need more info